# bash grep only numbers lastest database

Tags: html, bash, curl

```
curl -s http://virusradar.com/en/update/info/latest | grep -oP "(?\<=\<h1\>Update )\[0-9\]+"
```

When there was a base number in the header, it worked.
Now removed how to change the request.
Tell me good people.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

That URL appears to be defunct:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.virusradar.com/en/update/info/latest">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

What do you mean by "**base**" ?

Please provide the original form of the command, so we could see how it was (incorrectly?) modified.